# How Seed Data Relationships in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to put more than one subcategory per category or category per subcaregory and maybe a third category related on a seed.

for exemple:
() = have

```
category >>>> item 1 item 2 item 3 
subcategory >>>> item 2(subitem 1 subitem 2 subitem 3)
thirdcategory >>>> subitem 3(thirditem 1 thirditem 2)
```

Someone have a idea the way to acomplish this with seeds?

the relationships is:

category has_many subcategories

subcategories has_many thirdcategories

Answer (score 2):

If you have model Subcategory which belongs to Category you can do something like this in a seed file:

```
item1 = Category.create
subitem1 = Subcategory.create(category: item1)
```

It would be useful if you can explain exactly what are your models and relationships between them.

Answer (score 0):

I think we just need only model named Category for your subcategories issue:

Add field "parent_id:integer" to your Category model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :parent        , class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  has_many    :sub_categories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id"
end
```

seed file:

```
item_1 = Category.create()
item_2 = Category.create()
item_3 = Category.create()

subitem_1 = item_2.sub_categories.create()
subitem_2 = item_2.sub_categories.create()
subitem_3 = item_2.sub_categories.create()

thirditem_1 = item_3.sub_categories.create()
thirditem_2 = item_3.sub_categories.create()
```

Hope this help